# How can i get Data from Screen IN401000 using Webservices

Tags: c#, php, acumatica, webservices-client

Hello everyone i have this problem i try to get the info from this table (for example one inventoryID and all of the subarticle), but the consult is crashing because it's takes a lot of time.

I'm stuck right now, i have this in php but if someone could help me is fine if is C#

```
$Gate = new AcumaticaGate($user, $pass);
$schema = $Gate->Client->IN401000GetSchema(new IN401000GetSchema())->GetSchemaResult;
$Gate->Client->IN401000Clear(new IN401000Clear());

$export = new IN401000Export();
$export->commands = array
(
$schema->Selection->ServiceCommands->EveryInventoryID,
$schema->Selection->InventoryID,
//$schema->InventorySummary->DisplayName ,
//$schema->InventorySummary->InventoryID ,
//$schema->InventorySummary->Subitem ,
//$schema->InventorySummary->Warehouse ,
//$schema->InventorySummary->Available ,
//$schema->InventorySummary->BaseUnit,
);
$field = new Field();
$field->FieldName = "InventoryID";
$field->ObjectName = $schema->Selection->InventoryID->ObjectName;

$export->filters = array();

$filter_command = $Gate->PrepareSimpleFilter($field, FilterCondition::Contain, "10091"); // Filtro para buscar los 15 articulos Anteriores
array_push($export->filters,$filter_command);

$export->breakOnError = true;
$export->includeHeaders = false;
$export->topCount = 10;

try
{
    $export_result = $Gate->Client->IN401000Export($export)->ExportResult;
    unset($Gate->Client);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    console($e);
}

return $export_result->ArrayOfString;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with an inquiry screen, you always have to use `Submit` commit instead of `Export`. Below is the sample in C# showing how to export data via the Screen-Based API from the Inventory Summary (IN401000) screen for a given inventory item:

```
IN401000WebRef.Content itemSumSchema = IN401000context.GetSchema();
var itemSumCommands = new IN401000WebRef.Command[]
{
    new IN401000WebRef.Value
    {
        LinkedCommand = itemSumSchema.Selection.InventoryID,
        Value = item[0]
    },
    new IN401000WebRef.Value
    {
        LinkedCommand = itemSumSchema.Selection.ExpandByLotSerialNumber,
        Value = "True"
    },
    itemSumSchema.InventorySummary.Warehouse,
    itemSumSchema.InventorySummary.Location,
    itemSumSchema.InventorySummary.OnHand,
    itemSumSchema.InventorySummary.EstimatedTotalCost,
    itemSumSchema.InventorySummary.LotSerialNumber
};
var serials = IN401000context.Submit(itemSumCommands);
```

Comment: thanks, works.
But i have a question, is only for one Inventory by one? or is possible to get all the data no matters what inventory is used?

thanks a lot.
Beny

Comment: Due to original design of the **Inventory Summary** screen, there is no option to neither explore nor export data for more than one item at a time.